# Pi Crashes After Reboot

Tags: raspbian

I've noticed this a few times now. After I reboot the pi from the shutdown menu in Raspbian it reboots and doesn't get past the loading screen with a flashing dash in the top right corner, rendering it virtually useless. Not sure if SSH was working up to that point, kind of regret not checking, if I had I could of checked out the logs.

It's kind of annoying because I have to re-flash the image onto the sd card again every time it happens (happened about 5-6 times now). The only causes I can think of are a damaged SD, or perhaps its not fast enough, I've ruled out insufficient power draw, it has  a good adapter.

Comment: you can't rule out power issues without measuring the voltage at the board. Just because it says 5 volts and 2 Amps does not mean that is what the board is seeing for a myriad of reasons. This or the SD card is the likely cause of the issue. I would get a multi meter and measure the current then get a new SD Card.

Comment: I was really hoping that wasn't the case. I bought it from one of those bundles on Amazon for almost $100, you'd think they would put in a working ps.

Comment: Like I said get a meter and test it.

Comment: What happens if you choose to shut down, then (after waiting for the Activity light to stop flashing) cycle power to the Pi? Will it boot successfully from a power-off state?

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by the limited space in the partition of the SD card. I fixed it as follows:

1. First, I reinstalled the Raspbian image.
2. Then, I expanded the system space from the desktop:

*Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration* > **Filesystem Expand** button.

After this I could restart without problems.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely could be an issue with the firmware/version of Raspbian you have. Try running these through Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

In your case, since you can't reboot, just choose to shutdown your Pi.

Also, have you tried doing `startx`? If you have the option to login, and it shows a Terminal screen by itself, all across your screen with no GUI, then `startx` isn't pre-enabled.

#### Update:

If you aren't able to get to the shell, I would suggest you re-install NOOBS as well as all of Raspbian, and if that doesn't fix the boot-up issue (which I would be extremely surprised if it didn't), I would try to talk to somebody at the Pi Foundation.

Comment: Do *not* unplug your Pi without a shutdown!  That will very likely corrupt your filesystem!

Comment: Good point, it's not too likely but I shouldn't be mentioning it anyway. Thanks. @Lotharyx

Comment: Also I don't think he's getting as far as an interactive shell where he could try startx.